# How to decorate final class Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\BlockAdmin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Since `Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\BlockAdmin` is `@final` i should not extend from it. In [UPGRADE-3x.md](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/3.x/UPGRADE-3.x.md#closed-api) i can see that i should use decoration.

I am trying to this by decorating this final class with `App\Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin`.

`services.yaml` configuration:

```yaml
parameters:
    sonata.page.admin.page.class: App\Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin

services:
    Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin:
        alias: sonata.page.admin.page

    App\Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin:
        decorates: Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin
```

Decorator `App\Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin` body looks like this (i just invoke all the methods from final class in my decorator): https://gist.github.com/AVAW/910604534684eedb228f71df1d7deb40

But i get error:
[image]

Is there any possible way to decorate this final service or I am doing something wrong?

I am using:

```
sonata-project/admin-bundle: 3.107.3
sonata-project/page-bundle: 3.26.0
symfony: 4.4.41
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove the alias and directly use the sonata service name in the "decorate" ? like this :

```
services:
    App\Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin:
        decorates: 'sonata.page.admin.page'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Without alias the Symfony was throwing error that he does not know what is this class `Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin` in decorator, so i made alias.